# How to get the current sub procedure or function name and populate the cell value in a sheet called logs using excel macros?

Tags: excel, logging, vba

I have written a vb script that refreshes pivots, creates a new column next to the pivot and populates the values with certain formula. Given i have used lot of vb script code, i want to log certain messages in a sheet called 'logs' and i have a sub procedure that takes procedure name and message. I need your help when this procedure is called from my other sub procedures. Is there way i can refer the current sub procedure similar to using 'this' key in java so that i need not hard code the function name while calling my sub procedure that logs messages ?

Sub procedure that logs

```
Sub logMessages(subRoutine As String, msg As String) Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim numOfRows As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(logsSheet)
numOfRows = GetNumberOfRows(logsSheet)
ws.Range("A" & (numOfRows + 1)).Value = subRoutine & ":" & msg

End Sub
```

Comment: maybe `Application.Caller` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the below link it clearly says that the developer needs to hard code the sub procedure name
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/360180-determine-calling-procedure-name-visual-basic-applications.html